# how to update few fields of jsonb in golang cockroachdb

Tags: go, jsonb, cockroachdb

I have table in cockroachdb  as below:

```
         key        |                          value                           
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
  <host_ipa>        | {“student_name": “John", “degree": “Bachelors”, “university”: “KU”, “Company”: “ABC"}
```

Now I want to update only two keys of the `jsonb` - `degree` and `university`. How do I do that?

I have a solution but that requires all the four fields needs to be supplied.

Here is what I have in golang:

```
sqlCmd := fmt.Sprintf(" UPDATE %v set value = json_object('{%v, %v, %v, %v}'::string[], '{%v, %v, %v, %v}'::string[]) WHERE key = '%v' ",
        myTable,
        strconv.Quote("student_name”),
        strconv.Quote("degree"),
        strconv.Quote(“university”),
        strconv.Quote("Company"),
        strconv.Quote(student),
        strconv.Quote(newDegree),
        strconv.Quote(newUniversity),
        strconv.Quote(company),
        host)
    db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, DBConnStr)
    _, err = db.Exec(sqlCmd)
```

Working solution based on @Bergi:

```
    db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, DBConnStr)    
    sqlCmd := "UPDATE " + myTable + " SET value = value || jsonb_build_object(‘degree', $1::string, ‘university', $2::string) WHERE key = $3"
    _, err = db.Exec(sqlCmd, newDegree, newUniversity, host)
```

Comment: I assume your actual code doesn't have a quotes problem (`‘`vs`'`, `“`vs`"`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update individual properties of a jsonb object, use [`jsonb_set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```
UPDATE myTable SET value = jsonb_set(value, '{degree}', $1::text) WHERE key = $2
```

You can nest the calls to do multiple updates:

```
UPDATE myTable SET value = jsonb_set(jsonb_set(value, '{degree}', $1::text), '{university}', $2::text) WHERE key = $3
```

Alternatively, you can also simply use [the `||` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to merge new values into the object:

```
UPDATE myTable SET value = value || jsonb_build_object('degree', $1::text, 'university', $2::text) WHERE key = $3
```

Comment: I like [the `||` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) solution. But I ran into different error (edited my post with new code).

Comment: Hm, does it work when you hardcode the values? I'm not sure how parameterised queries work in Go.

Comment: Yes, the hard coded values does work (I tried with fmt.Sprintf()). But parametrised values seems avoid the SQL injections, so I was leaning for it. I also tried passing ‘“string”’ kind of parameters, it did not work.

Comment: Hm, according to [this article](https://www.calhoun.io/inserting-records-into-a-postgresql-database-with-gos-database-sql-package/), you're doing everything right...

Comment: Oh, I guess I was confused by the "placeholder" term in the error message. I guess that Postgres simply cannot infer the type of the expression from the context (because `jsonb_build_object` takes `any`) and doesn't derive it dynamically from the value you are passing as a parameter. So let's be explicit that these will be strings. If you were going to put a number or boolean or json in the property, specify that instead.

Comment: I specified the types for the updated properties as `$1::string and $2::string`. This time `db.Exec()` is successful. But it did not really update the row.

Comment: Yep, `WHERE key = $3` seems working fine because its not part of `jsonb`.

Comment: I did enable the cockroachdb sql logging on a node. And I could see the issue quickly. @Bergi, your recommendations were perfect - jsonb properties need to have type specified, in my case it is `$1::string and $2::string` or `$1::text and $2::text`.